# Building and Linking libraries with C++ and SFML

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, sfml, building

I'm really inexperianced with building libraries as a whole and I'm unsure of what search terms I should be using to find what I'm looking for, so I figured I'd ask here.

I'm currently trying to build LTBL2 (Let there be light 2) using cmake and visual studio 2015, I'll walk you through what I've done so far, then where I want to go.

At this point, I'm pretty sure I've build the library.

I started by configuring and building it for VS 14 2015 with the following settings:

[Image of cmake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW6u8.jpg)

I then opened the LTBL2.sln that I got from it. I built the solution in both debug and release, [here are some screenshots of what I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW6u8.jpg)

I have no idea where to go from here. Did I correctly build the solution? If not, could I have an explenation on what went wrong. If everything seems fine and normal, how do I then link these files into my SFML project?

I feel like I don't quite understand how linking and building libraries in C++ works, does anyone know of some good resources for learning more about these things?

Comment: Could you please take the info from your screenshots and put it in the question? Links can die or be inaccessible, in my case I can't reach them. As for one of your issues, ALL_BUILD.vcxproj is just a Visual Studio Project, not the solution. There should be a ````.sln```` file created. Open that and build the solution.

Comment: As for resources, if you are curious about CMake they have some [tutorials](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake) on their wiki page.

Comment: There was a solution that I built, I fixed my question. As for screenshots, I don't seem to be able to add them to my question directly, so I have to include a link. Basically, all I have in my debug folder is a `.dll` a `.ilk` and a `.pdb` none of which I am familiar working with. Should I have expected this result? I also have a `LTBL2.dir` folder that includes a debug and a release, but that only contains .obj files.

Comment: I meant that whatever output in the screenshots you deem important, write in text in the question. If we are looking at a drawing of something it's probably not code related :)

DLL is what you are looking for, it's a [dynamic link library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library). There should also be a ````.lib```` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: There is no .lib file anywhere in my build.